# What response does leaflet routing machine expect from a custom OSRM router?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I have OSRM (node-osrm) set up locally and it produces correct results for routes on the server. However, when I request routes from it via leaflet routing machine I get the following error in the browser:

```
leaflet-routing-machine.js:2605 Routing error: Object {status: undefined}status: undefined__proto__: ObjectdefaultErrorHandler 

@ leaflet-routing-machine.js:2605fire 
@ leaflet-src.js:588(anonymous function) 
@ leaflet-routing-machine.js:2900_routeDone 
@ leaflet-routing-machine.js:4693(anonymous function) 
@ leaflet-routing-machine.js:4645loaded 
@ leaflet-routing-machine.js:46
```

The app works with the mapbox router and the response looks slight different (different order).

Answer (score 1):

After comparing responses from a commercial server and my own server I found the problem: Leaflet routing machine (LRM) expects a route response containing:

- name,
- summary,
- coordinates,
- waypoints,
- instructions.

  [LRM docs on iRoute](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#iroute)

The OSRM engine does not include instructions out-of-the-box in the response, these must be added on the server after the route is returned by OSRM. The osrm-text-instructions plugin does so nicely. [osrm-text-instructions](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-text-instructions)